# What is this javascript code doing?

Tags: javascript

```
this.String = {
    Get : function (val) {
        return function() {
            return val;
        }
    }
};
```

What is the ':' doing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Others have already explained what this code does. It creates an object (called `this.String`) that contains a single function (called `Get`). I'd like to explain when you could use this function.

This function can be useful in cases where you need a higher order function (that is a function that expects another function as its argument).

Say you have a function that does something to each element of an `Array`, lets call it `map`. You could use this function like so:

```
function inc (x)
{
    return x + 1;
}
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var newArr = arr.map(inc);
```

What the `map` function will do, is create a new array containing the values `[2, 3, 4]`. It will do this by calling the function `inc` with each element of the array.

Now, if you use this method a lot, you might continuously be calling `map` with all sorts of arguments:

```
arr.map(inc); // to increase each element
arr.map(even); // to create a list of booleans (even or odd)
arr.map(toString); // to create a list of strings
```

If for some reason you'd want to replace the entire array with the same string (but keeping the array of the same size), you could call it like so:

```
arr.map(this.String.Get("my String"));
```

This will create a new array of the same size as `arr`, but just containing the string `"my String"` over and over again.

Note that in some languages, this function is predefined and called `const` or `constant` (since it will always return the same value, each time you call it, no matter what its arguments are).

---

Now, if you think that this example isn't very useful, I would agree with you. But there are cases, when programming with higher order functions, when this technique is used.

For example, it can be useful if you have a tree you want to 'clear' of its values but keep the structure of the tree. You could do `tree.map(this.String.Get("default value"))` and get a whole new tree is created that has the exact same shape as the original, but none of its values.

Answer (score 10):

`this.String = {}` specifies an object.  `Get` is a property of that object.  In javascript, object properties and their values are separated by a colon ':'.

So, per the example, you would call the function like this

```
this.String.Get('some string');
```

More examples:

```
var foo = {
  bar : 'foobar',
  other : {
     a : 'wowza'
  }
}
alert(foo.bar); //alerts 'foobar'
alert(foo.other.a) //alerts 'wowza'
```

Comment: But what is the point of the example the author has given? I find this question interesting because it's so weird :p

Comment: @TimothyP, That wasn't the poster's question though

Comment: I can't believe the number of upvotes on this answer when it doesn't approach an answer to the question apart from describing some very basic object construction code.

Comment: @Anthony - agreed, this is an MSDN answer, i.e. half of what you need to know

Answer (score 4):

It assigns an object that has a property "Get" to `this.String`. "Get" is assigned an anonymous function, which will return a function that just returns the argument that was given to the first returning function. Sounds strange, but here is how it can be used:

```
var ten = this.String["Get"](10)();
```

`ten` will then contain a 10. Instead, you could have written the equivalent

```
var ten = this.String.Get(10)();

// saving the returned function can have more use:
var generatingFunction = this.String.Get("something");
alert(generatingFunction()); // displays "something"
```

That is, `:` just assigns some value to a property.

Comment: ah, nice. i didn't expect my java-script n00biness hit the right words (well, roughly at least) :p i left explaining what exactly ':' does the other ones and concentrated on what that code does at large. thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be a bit superflous since Tom's is a good answer but just to boil it down and be complete:-

```
this.String = {};
```

Adds an object to the current object with the property name of `String`.

```
var fn = function(val) {
    return function() { return(val); }
}
```

Returns a function from a closure which in turn returns the parameter used in creating the closure.  Hence:-

```
var fnInner = fn("Hello World!");
alert(fnInner()); // Displays Hello World!
```

In combination then:-

```
this.String = { Get: function(val) {
    return function() { return(val); }
}
```

Adds an object to the current object with the property name of `String` that has a method called `Get` that returns a function from a closure which in turn returns the parameter used in creating the closure.

```
var fnInner = this.String.Get("Yasso!");
alert(fnInner()); //displays Yasso!
```