# Javascript function literals?

Tags: javascript, json, object, literals

I have stumbled upon this code

```
var Actors = {

    init: function(config){
        this.config = config;
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function(){
        this.config.letterSelection.on('change',this.fetchActors );
    },

    fetchActors: function(){
        console.log('fetching');
    }
};
```

And at first I was thinking what kind of Javascript is this. I don't know what to search for. so I guess asking it here is approrpriate

What I understand is that var Actors is an object.
but what about these?

```
 init: function(config){
        this.config = config;
        this.bindEvents();
    },
```

What do you specifically call the literal "init" ? is it called an object literal? after the init it has a function attached to it what do you call it?

I understand what the code is doing. but I don't know what to call them in technical terms.
so what type of javascript is this? why does a word "init" has a function to it

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this javascript code doing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481518/what-is-this-javascript-code-doing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is kinda functional language, which means that functions are first-class objects in it. So if you have a variable, then you can assign to it some string, some number, some object or some function, like this:

```
var a;
a = function() {};
a(); // Call this function
```

In the same way you can assign a function to an object property, like this:

```
var a = {};
a.myProp = function() {};
a.myProp(); // Call this function
```

But when you call your function like `a.myProp()`, then this function also receives a special argument called `this` which points to `a`.

So, in your case `Actors` is assigned object literal, which has a property `init`, which is assigned a function. You can call it `method`, but this is a concept from other OO languages. Here, it's just a property which is assigned a function.

Comment: No, Actors is an object, not object constructor. In JavaScript functions are object constructors, for example:
var a = function() { this.MyProp = 1; }
a.prototype = { MyMethod: function () {}, MyMethod2: function() {}};

var b = new a();

Comment: You should read some basic documentation on JavaScript object model

Comment: ohh yeah that's how it goes. I totally forgot! thanks anyway. where can I see the basic documentation of the javaScript Object model?

Comment: For example, here http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html or here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 3):

> What do you specifically call the literal "init" ? is it called an object literal?

A property. The object literal is `{}`

> after the init it has a function attached to it what do you call it?

A method.

> why does a word "init" has a function to it

Because it is useful to organise a bunch of related "stuff" by assigning the them to object properties.

It becomes more so when functions can use `this` to operate on the object they are associated with.

Comment: so the init property has a method attached to it?

Comment: No, it has a function assigned to it so it becomes a method.

Comment: so init is a method? am I getting it right. also is this somehow related to JSON? or is this JSON?

Comment: JSON is a special subset of JavaScript language based on object literal syntax. But JSON syntax doesn't allow functions, so this is not JSON.